# Найти сумму целых чисел введёных с клавиатуры

Tags: python, python-3.x

Найти сумму целых чисел введёных с клавиатуры, **без использования `for, while, sum, map, reduce, fiter, import, eval, exec, compile, single`**

```
list1 = list(map(int,input().split()))
suma = 0
for range1 in range(len(list1)):
    suma += list1[range1]
print(suma)
```

Я смог сделать, но только с for...
Может кто-нибудь знает как это сделать?

Comment: Не только с `for`, но и с `map`

Comment: Не, ну без `import` - это уж вообще...

Comment: а if можно использовать?

Comment: в пайтоне нет рекурсий?

Answer (score 5):

например так:

```
arr = list(map(int,input().split()))

def add(arr, res = 0):
    return res if len(arr) == 0 else (res + arr[0] + add(arr[1:], res))

print(add(arr))
```

вариант 2 (как вариант 1, только без излишеств)

```
def add(arr):
    return arr[0] if len(arr) == 1 else (arr[0] + add(arr[1:]))

print(add(arr))
```

вариант 3:

если нельзя даже данные получать с этими командами, тогда так:

```
def add(arr):
    return int(arr[0]) if len(arr) == 1 else (int(arr[0]) + add(arr[1:]))

print(add(input().split()))
```

вариант 4 (как и вариант 3, но покороче):

```
def add(arr):
    return (int(arr[0]) + add(arr[1:])) if arr else 0

print(add(input().split()))
```

вариант 5 (как и вариант 4, но короче на 1 (!!!) букву)

```
def add(arr):
    return (int(arr.pop()) + add(arr)) if arr else 0

print(add(input().split()))
```

Comment: у вас используется `map` :)

Comment: @Danis - это не мой алгоритм - я лишь работаю с массивом чисел :) или в задаче и там нельзя?

Comment: Найти сумму целых чисел **введёных с клавиатуры**

Comment: @Danis, понял, добавил вариант 3

Comment: `f=lambda x,*l:int(x)+(l and f(*l)or 0)` 38 символов

Comment: @Danis, что-то у меня этот не заработал - сделал такой `f=lambda a:a and(int(a.pop())+f(a))or 0` - 40 символов

Comment: Просто у меня другие входные данные. Их надо распокавать `f(*arr)`

Answer (score 3):

можно с помощью рекурсия

```
def f(arr):
    if arr == []:
        return 0
    return int(arr[0]) + f(arr[1:])

print(f(input().split()))
```